# $ \Delta p=0$ and $(\nabla p)\cdot \nu\big|_{\partial\Omega}=0 $ in $H^1(\Omega)$ implies $p$ is a constant

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

In the proof of a theorem regarding the characterization of some space in *Temam's Navier Stokes Equations* (p11 (1.37)), the following argument is made.

> Suppose $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $p\in H^1(\Omega)$ is such that
>   $$
> \Delta p=0, \quad(\nabla p)\cdot \nu\big|_{\partial\Omega}=0
> $$
>   where $\nu$ is the unit outer normal. Then $p$ is a constant.

---

I don't have much experience solving PDE in terms of distributions. Would anybody come up with a reference or giving an argument regarding why the above is true?

Comment: This sounds like the Dirichlet problem. The fact that $\Delta p = 0$, means that $p$ is harmonic, so everything matches up. See wikipedia for an intro

Comment: @J.Marx-Kuo: No. This is not the Dirichlet problem. It is Neumann problem. Besides, $p\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\Delta p=0$ is in the sense of distribution.

Comment: @ Jack: Sorry I get the two confused. I also didn't see the part about distributions, which puts the question into the realm of math I don't know, Do you have a link of the text? This is mostly for my curiosity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $f∈ H^1$, $$ 0  = ∫_\Omega fΔ p = ∫_{\partial \Omega}f ∇ p· \nu - ∫_\Omega∇ f ∇ p $$
so $∫_\Omega ∇ f ∇ p = 0$. With $f=p$, $‖∇ p‖_{L^2} = 0$. By Poincaré, 
$$\left\| p - \frac{1}{|\Omega|}∫_\Omega p\right\|_{L^2} \leq C‖∇ p‖_{L^2} = 0$$
so $p$ equals the constant $\frac{1}{|\Omega|}∫_\Omega p$ (almost everywhere).

Comment: Don't you need $f\in H^1_0$ to use it as a test function?

Comment: @Del if it was a problem about $H^{-1}$ then sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you define $\nabla p\cdot\nu$ on $\partial\Omega$?

Comment: @Jack Usually you wouldn't because $H^1$ isn't good enough but we were told it's 0.

Comment: For the Poincaré part, are you using the fact that the gradient of a constant is zero?

Comment: Well yes bas long as you know that the gradient here is understood in the weak sense.

Comment: I don't quite get the last part of your argument. Would you elaborate How you use the Poincaré?

Comment: It's literally written out above, that line is precisely (one of the inequalities people call) Poincare inequality?

Comment: It seems that one can put arbitrary constant on the LHS. How do you get $\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega p$?

Comment: That is part of the statement of Poincare. I would link you but I'm on my phone, try google?

Comment: Fair enough. You are using the version different from the one I thought. The Poincaré-Wirtinger inequality in Wikipedia. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately they are all called Poincare. Or at least Poincare-type in Evans if I recall correctly. Glad you understand :)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of a reference, this appears in an exercise of Evans's PDE (problem 10 in chapter 6 with smoother assumption of $\partial\Omega$). Also, one should assume that $\Omega$ is connected in the statement.